# Speech options not working on One Note Immersive Reader

Tags: microsoft-onenote, speech

I installed the One Note Learning Tool for my son who has special needs but the only voices available to me are “Microsoft David” and “Microsoft Zira” which are difficult for him to understand due to the accent.

I have tried downloading English(India) and it is showing as default language however still the options of “Microsoft Heera” and “Microsoft Ravi” are not showing in the Immersive Reader in speech.

How do I get these languages to work in Immersive Reader?